# Embed vectorized PDF image in HTML

Tags: html, pdf, vector-graphics

I have a vectorized image save as a PDF (probably output by `matplotlib` or PowerPoint) and I would like to embed it in a HTML page.

Note that `<embed>` does not do the work, since it creates an embedded PDF viewer, but I would rather see a simple vectorized image (as if it was a PNG).

For now my only solution is to convert it to PNG with an online converter, but that outputs a rasterized image, which is okay but not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using pdf.js? It's a pure HTML5/JavaScript renderer. http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js